# WordPress Import Users from Prestashop Password reHash

Tags: wordpress, prestashop, password-encryption

I have imported our old Prestashop users into the wp_users table and obviously the Passwords are not in the WP format so our user can not login with their Prestashop Password.

I have tried this plugin but its not working at all:

https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/prestashop-user-compatibility

I then took a look at the reset password codex and found the below script but this is still not working.

```
  require_once 'wp-config.php';
$sql="SELECT user_pass,ID FROM wp_users WHERE ID = '279'";
$find = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($find))
  {

  $current_password = $row['user_pass'];
  $current_id = $row['ID'];
  $hashed_password = wp_hash_password( $current_password );

  $update_sql= "UPDATE wp_users SET user_pass = '" . $hashed_password . "' WHERE ID = " . $current_id . "";
  $update = mysql_query($update_sql) or die(mysql_error());  

  echo $current_id . " " . $hashed_password;
  echo "<br />";
  }
```

After running the code above the password looks like the same format in phpMyAdmin but still can not login.  I am using wooCommerce with WordPress.

Prestashop Password: 0f1a0cf4f0a2ad0fe4f760bfcd981646
After Script Above: $P$Bt1yBukTlFIa6PHz9hb98VeLKcfDu30

Any ideas please?

Thanks

Jon

/***** UPDATE *******/

Managed to get the plugin above to do something but it wont match the passwords:

```
$ps_salt = 'MY COOKIE KEY';

    $wp_hashed_pw = $user->user_pass."<br />"; // password stored in WPDB
    $ps_hashed_pw = md5($ps_salt.$password);
    // this means that the user's password in the DB is an old Prestashop password
    // if the password is correct, we rehash and update it
    if($ps_hashed_pw == $user->user_pass) {
        wp_set_password( $password, $user->id );

    }
```

So It basically when user logs in with Prestashop password it runs the code and then updates to wordpress format, can you see anything wrong with above?

Comment: UPDATE:  The script above seems to be taking the Prestashop password and encrypting that so I can now login with the Prestashop encrypted password: 0f1a0cf4f0a2ad0fe4f760bfcd981646  and not the real Prestasho password?

Comment: Prestashop also hashing the password before storing so you won't be able to get real/actual password.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reverse engineer PrestaShop passwords. Most probably the script above makes sure that you can login with the hash of the PrestaShop password.

So if your password is:

mysecredword

it is hashed in PrestaShop like:

0f1a0cf4f0a2ad0fe4f760bfcd981646

and the script above hashed that password and it becames:

$P$Bt1yBukTlFIa6PHz9hb98VeLKcfDu30

So now you can login in wordpress with:

0f1a0cf4f0a2ad0fe4f760bfcd981646

but not with the original customer password, which is:

mysecredword

PrestaShop hashes the password the following way:

MD5('_COOKIE_KEY_password')

where "password" is the customer password and _COOKIE_KEY_ is a PHP constant from /config/settings.inc.php

Comment: Thanks for answer.  I am wondering how Prestashop hashes its passwords, do you know?

Comment: Just updated Question, if you have the time to have a look please, much apprectiated.